# rotate an image and translate it using xml

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I need help with this exercise. I need to insert an image in an xml file, it must rotate for the first two seconds and at the end of which it must be translated by 100, finally the image must remain in the final position.
In activity_main.xml I am trying like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vEPxtF9" />
```

This only rotates the image.
Is it possible to do this using only an xml file without java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is good enough for you (it is kind of "just by xml")

You can use `RotateAnimation` on your `View`.

> This is rotation.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="90"
  android:toDegrees="100"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="2000"/>
```

And then just give this animation to your `View`:

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
myView.startAnimation(rotation);
```